# Why does my aggregate return duplicate data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, aggregate

I'm fairly new to mongo aggregation so my nose is in the mongo docs to try and figure it out. Getting pretty close! I'm running some queries on my data sets to get the current results from a save data document. But the response I get is a duplicate of the first result in the set.

```
const result = await MemoryCard.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'users',
        localField: 'owner',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'owner',
      },
    },
    {'$unwind': '$owner'},
    {$unwind: '$progress'},
    {$match: {
      'progress.createdAt': {
        $gte: d,
        $lte: new Date(),
      },
      'progress.file_one': {$eq: true},
      'progress.file_two': {$eq: true},
    }},
    {$unwind: '$profiles'},
    {
      '$project': {
        'owner.email': 1,
        'owner.username': 1,
        'progress': 1,
        'profiles': 1,
      },
    },
  ]);
```

In the result I get back you can tell that the first bit is duplicated:

````
[
    {
        "_id": "5ca8a0bf6a45e10ad41a7fb3",
        "owner": {
            "email": "kevin2@s*******.com",
            "username": "kevin"
        },
        "profiles": {
            "data": [
                100,
                100,
                84,
                91,
                100
            ],
            "tools": [
                "5c7d4c9971338741c09c6c68",
                "5c7d4c9971338741c09c6c6b",
                "5c7d4c9971338741c09c6c74",
                "5c7d4c9971338741c09c6c73",
                "5c7d4c9971338741c09c6c75"
            ],
            "timestamp": "2019-04-06T12:51:07.151Z",
            "_id": "5ca8a0bf6a45e10ad41a7fb4",
            "profile_id": "5c864fd3f98eeb1afc9cc809",
            "createdAt": "2019-04-06T12:51:11.471Z",
            "updatedAt": "2019-04-06T12:51:11.471Z"
        },
        "progress": {
            "_id": "5caf4675999c0c14d0cda13e",
            "tool": "5c7d4c9971338741c09c6c66",
            "createdAt": "2019-04-11T13:51:49.352Z",
            "updatedAt": "2019-04-11T13:55:17.527Z",
            "file_two": true,
            "file_one": true
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ca8a0bf6a45e10ad41a7fb3",
        "owner": {
            "email": "kevin2@s********.com",
            "username": "kevin"
        },
        "profiles": {
            "data": [
                100,
                100,
                84,
                91,
                100
            ],
            "tools": [
                "5c7d4c9971338741c09c6c68",
                "5c7d4c9971338741c09c6c6b",
                "5c7d4c9971338741c09c6c74",
                "5c7d4c9971338741c09c6c73",
                "5c7d4c9971338741c09c6c75"
            ],
            "timestamp": "2019-04-06T12:51:07.151Z",
            "_id": "5ca8a0bf6a45e10ad41a7fb4",
            "profile_id": "5c864fd3f98eeb1afc9cc809",
            "createdAt": "2019-01-06T12:51:11.471Z",
            "updatedAt": "2019-01-06T12:51:11.471Z"
        },
        "progress": {
            "_id": "5caf4675999c0c14d0cda13e",
            "tool": "5c7d4c9971338741c09c6c66",
            "createdAt": "2019-04-11T13:51:49.352Z",
            "updatedAt": "2019-04-11T13:55:17.527Z",
            "file_two": true,
            "file_one": true
        }
    }
]```

Where as i'm expecting multiple users.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed it by realising that the double entries were separated and had to be grouped! Below my fixed query.

```
const result = await MemoryCard.aggregate([
    {$match: {'updatedAt': {
      $gte: d,
      $lte: new Date(),
    }}},
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'users',
        localField: 'owner',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'owner',
      },
    },
    {$unwind: '$owner'},
    {$unwind: '$profiles'},
    {$match: {
      'progress.createdAt': {
        $gte: d,
        $lte: new Date(),
      },
      'progress.file_one': {$eq: true},
      'progress.file_two': {$eq: true},
    }},
    {$unwind: '$progress'},
    {
      $group: {
        '_id': '$_id',
        'owner': {$first: '$owner'},
        'progress': {$addToSet: '$progress'},
        'profiles': {$last: '$profiles'},
      },
    },
    {
      '$project': {
        'owner.email': '$owner.email',
        'owner.username': '$owner.username',
        'progress': '$progress',
        'profile': '$profiles',
      },
    },
  ]);
```